# How do I define a builder pattern hierarchy where the setters can be called in any order

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class, builder

Consider the abstract Data class with an abstract Builder:

```
abstract class Data {

    abstract static class Builder<T extends Data> {

        private String one;

        protected Builder() {
            this.one = null;
        }

        public final Builder<T> withOne(final String value) {
            this.one = value;
            return this;
        }

        protected abstract T build();
    }

    private final String one;

    protected Data(final Builder<? extends Data> builder) {
        this.one = builder.one;
    }

    public final String getOne() {
        return this.one;
    }
}
```

The class is extended, which also includes its own extended Builder:

```
public final class Extension extends Data {

    public static final class ExtensionBuilder extends Data.Builder<Extension> {

        private String two;

        private ExtensionBuilder() {
            super();
            this.two = null;
        }

        public static final ExtensionBuilder newInstance() {
            return new ExtensionBuilder();
        }

        public final ExtensionBuilder withTwo(final String value) {
            this.two = value;
            return this;
        }

        public final Extension build() {
            return new Extension(this);
        }
    }

    private final String two;

    private Extension(final ExtensionBuilder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.two = builder.two;
    }

    public final String getTwo() {
        return this.two;
    }
}
```

The Extension object gets all methods from both classes. However the order the setter methods is called is important. This is OK:

```
Extension one = Extension.ExtensionBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .withTwo("two")
                .withOne("one")
                .build();
```

Whereas this produces a compilation error:

```
Extension two = Extension.ExtensionBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .withOne("one")
                .withTwo("two")
                .build();
```

I know the reason why, the withOne() setter has downcast the type of Builder object from the concrete class to the abstract one. I would like to know what I need to do to solve this, so setters can be called in any order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want (or can't) override the `withOne` method in the `ExtensionBuilder` class as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48429910/1876620), you can use a [recursively bounded generic type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) for your builder:

```
abstract static class Builder<T extends Data, B extends Builder<T, B>> {

    private String one;

    protected Builder() {
        this.one = null;
    }

    public final B withOne(final String value) {
        this.one = value;
        return (B) this;
    }

    protected abstract T build();
}
```

Then, declare the `ExtensionBuilder` class as follows:

```
public static final class ExtensionBuilder 
    extends Data.Builder<Extension, ExtensionBuilder>
```

This will allow you to use the most concrete builder's methods in any order, because the compiler now knows the static type of the concrete builder.

**EDIT:**
As pointed out by [@Radiodef in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48429730/how-do-i-define-a-builder-pattern-heirarchy-where-the-setters-can-be-called-in-a#comment83851656_48430421), there's an alternative to the cast, which consists of declaring a `protected abstract B getThis()` method in the `Builder` class:

```
abstract static class Builder<T extends Data, B extends Builder<T, B>> {

    private String one;

    protected Builder() {
        this.one = null;
    }

    protected abstract B getThis();

    public final B withOne(final String value) {
        this.one = value;
        return getThis(); // no need to cast now
    }

    protected abstract T build();
}
```

And of course in the `ExtensionBuilder` you should implement it as:

```
@Override
protected ExtensionBuilder getThis() { return this; }
```

Here's the source: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ205

Comment: The unchecked cast can be avoided with a method `protected abstract B getThis();`, as described by e.g. Angelika Langer's FAQ: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ205

Comment: @Radiodef True, thanks for the link, I will add that in an edit. Anyways, it's quite safe to assume that you will never declare e.g. `ExtensionBuilder` as `class ExtensionBuilder extends Builder<T, SomeOtherExtensionBuilder>`

Comment: Also, the `getThis()` idiom doesn't prevent the subclass from returning something other than `this`, so it's not really any "safer" than the unchecked cast. It just side-steps the issue of understanding what unchecked casting is really doing.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner you gave me a lot of reading via this answer! thank you

Comment: @MarcusMacWilliam You're most welcome. Bear in mind that this is not bullet-proof. It gets messy and complicated for hierarchies of more than one level, and I'm not sure if it can be safely applied when the parent class is not abstract. But it was a perfect fit for your question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `Builder`'s `withOne` method returns a `Builder<T>`, not a `ExtensionBuilder`, so the compiler doesn't see that there is a `withTwo` method.

You need to override `withOne` so it has the same functionality but it returns something of type `ExtensionBuilder`.

First, make `withOne` *not* `final` in `Builder` so you can override it in `ExtensionBuilder`.

Then, override it.  Just call the overridden method and return `this` to retain the same functionality.

```
@Override
public ExtensionBuilder withOne(final String value) {
    super.withOne(value);
    return this;            
}
```

Comment: That would work, but I was specifically attempting to constrain the design, so that the real setter and getter on the Data class, deliberately cannot be overridden. I think I have not got the generics right, there should be a way to define that for an instance of the ExtensionBuilder the withOne method thinks it is returning an ExtensionBuilder rather than a Builder<Extension>.

Comment: It's not that you can't the generics right.  If `withOne` is `final`, it can't be overridden to return a more specific type.  The return type must be `Builder<T>`, and no matter what `T` is, the compiler doesn't see the `withTwo` method in the `Builder` class.

Answer (score 3):

You are conflating two altogether different things.  The Builder pattern is about decoupling object creation from specification of object properties.  Your issue is not with that at all, but rather with your use of method chaining as an implementation strategy.  To demonstrate this, I observe that exactly the order of builder method invocations you like can be achieved with your *current* design by dumping the method chaining:

```
Extension.ExtensionBuilder builder = Extension.ExtensionBuilder.newInstance();
builder.withOne("one");
builder.withTwo("two");
Extension two = builder.build();
```

Method chaining has always been a bit controversial.  The Streams API has lately given it some positive mind share, but that doesn't make it appropriate for all cases.  One of its problems is indeed exactly what you describe: that it doesn't play nicely with inheritance.